# Laravel - datatable how to pass id when exit the input field in the current row

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable

its very clear question, I have problem with passing id to controller on exit of input field which exist in the same row of the id that I want to pass?
So Again how can I do pass two variables, variable of the input field and the id of the row that this input field exists in?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var oTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({
            dom: 'flBrtip',
               processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                 url: 'custom-filter-data',
         columns : [
         {data: 'id'},  
         {data: 'details', name: 'details'},
          {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
         {data: 'vendor_id',render: function (data) {        
           return ('<label hidden>'+data+'</label> <input type="text" id="vendor" class="vendor" onClick="this.select();" value="'+data+'">');   
           }}, 
             ],
         pageLength: 10,
        };
    oTable.draw();
   </script>
```

I know how to pass variables using ajax like in this below

```
    $( "#vendor" ).on('blur', function() { 
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Vendor_Save',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
             'currentid': {data: 'id'},
             'current_vendor_id': {data: 'vendor_id'},

        },
        success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
            }
          });

              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me you got the id:
Not tested, but the below is my way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var oTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({
        dom: 'flBrtip',
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
             url: 'custom-filter-data',
             columns : [
                    {data: 'id'},  
                    {data: 'details', name: 'details'},
                    {data: 'description', name: 'description'},

                    {
                        mRender: function (data, type, row) {                   
                            return '<label hidden>'+data+'</label> <input type="text" id="vendor" class="vendor" data-id="'+row.id+'" onClick="this.select();" value="'+data+'">';
                        }
                    },
            ],
             pageLength: 10,
    };
    oTable.draw();
</script>




    $(document).on('blur focusout', "#vendor", function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");

        alert(id); //Tell me you are getting the id

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Vendor_Save',
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'currentid': {data: 'id'},
                'current_vendor_id': {data: 'vendor_id'},
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: The problem is the script  $( "#vendor" ).on('blur', function() {... wont work becuase its out of the previous code that has the input

Comment: check the updated code added: `$(document).on('blur focusout', "#vendor", function(){`, try now